# Papers/studies about shedding aerodynamic lifting surfaces with booster

Tags: history, spacecraft, reference-request, stages, stage-separation

(This post has been updated to fulfil community guidelines on specificity)

Here's my relevant scenario:
A lifting-body Orbital Vehicle, and a turboramjet booster that (the most important part) includes the wings used to lift the weight of the initial total vehicle.
The ramjet and wings are dropped together at Mach. 6, and make a controlled gliding landing to a runway downrange.
The Orbital Vehicle, running on a closed cycle LH2/LO2, ascends to ~150km and a speed of ~7.8-8 km/s, and deploys it's payload.
It then descends to land, now fully dry of it's fuel, and lands at the runway it took off from.
The ditching of the wings with the booster reduces unnecessary weight for getting to orbit, like the wings of the Space Shuttle.

I'm looking for a way to find related papers, reports, etc that could help me find past information on this style of launch.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried NASA NTRS / STI ?

Comment: There's the meta post [Resources and References on the Topic of Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/resources-and-references-on-the-topic-of-space-exploration), but I don't know if it will be helpful looking for your database.  You might try asking about your obscure launch-vehicle staging option directly as well; it doesn't always work well here, but sometimes it does.

Comment: An edit to the question to narrow the focus to reference requests about your specific topic might stop the close-voting. I personally haven't VTC, but it does seem kind of broad.

Comment: @RegenerativelyCooledAstronaut I think Skylon might interest you (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylon_(spacecraft))

Comment: What have you tried searching for?  Looking for "winged turboramjet booster" has turned up a number of TSTO proposals, mostly around the 90s, like the MIG AKS.  I don't know if any precisely fit what you're looking for, but presumably you can mix-and-match turboramjet booster proposals and lifting body orbiter/lander vehicle proposals.

Comment: Do you actually propose a vehicle that has 5 times the delta-v of the space shuttle, enters atmosphere with 8 times the kinetic energy of the shuttle and lands unpowered without wings?

Comment: I miss combined cycle engines.

Comment: 25.5 km/s should be 25.5 kft/s, or 25500 feet per second, reasonable orbital velocity.

Comment: @WHG Yeah, I was aiming for the target speed of the National Space Plane, a LH2 Scramjet SSTO from the (1980s?)

Comment: Oh and I've changed the top velocity: My bad, 7.8-8.0 km/s, or orbital speed at 150km

Comment: If you're interested in NASP, there are lots of papers on NTRS about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hits from a shallow dive into NTRS -

- [Performance estimates for space shuttle vehicles using a hydrogen or a methane fueled turboramjet powered first stage](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19720007229/downloads/19720007229.pdf) Second stage is winged, but otherwise looks applicable

[image]

- [Turbojet-ramjet propulsion system for all-body hypersonic aircraft](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710005905/downloads/19710005905.pdf) Single stage, but it's a lifting body
- [Beta 2: A near term, fully reusable, horizontal takeoff and landing two-stage-to-orbit launch vehicle concept](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19920012293/downloads/19920012293.pdf) First stage turboramjet, second stage is kind of a stretched Shuttle orbiter

How to search on NTRS:

- Browse to https://ntrs.nasa.gov/ and hit the blue "Start Search" button under "Publicly Available Content". The page will refresh and display a search box at the top.
- For this search, I just typed in *turboramjet*. The site has an annoying search-before-you-finish-typing setup but just ignore that.
- The site then displays a list of "finds" with the search text highlighted. On the left of the page, fields are provided so that you can try and filter the results, but I rarely do this.
- I just scrolled through the search results and clicked on ones that seemed applicable.

Others:

You should definitely read *The Hypersonic Revolution* for deep background. [Volume 1](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA441127.pdf)  [Volume 2](https://media.defense.gov/2010/Sep/27/2001329812/-1/-1/0/AFD-100927-035.pdf)

Comment: upvoted, but I think this would be improved by some details of your dive (search terms / methods as applicable; I don't think I've ever searched NTRS directly rather than letting Google or Duckduckgo search it for me)

Comment: @ErinAnne done, thanks for the suggestion.